# How do I build sdl2 with meson?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, meson-build

Using this meson file,

```
project('mytest', 'c')
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')

deps = []
deps += dependency('sdl2',
  required: true,
  static: true,
  method: 'pkg-config')


executable('demo', 
           'src/main.c', 
           dependencies : deps,
           gui_app: true)
```

I get the following error

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

This seems to be related to the `SDLmain.lib` (I'm sure it exist).
How would you force the linker to link to this library?

I'm on windows 10, using the MSVC compiler.

Comment: Did you link against `SDLmain.lib`?

Comment: No ! How do you do so? `dependency` doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building a gui app, not a terminal app. With MSVC, when you set `gui_app : true` (or in more recent versions of meson `win_subsystem : 'windows'`) you don't provide a `main` function, you provide `WinMain` function instead.

[See the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-160)

Under the hood this option is passing `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` to the compiler